# Rails API user auth accepts api calls from React proxy but not directly from host url

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am currently trying to deploy a React front end and rails API web application.  In development, I set up a proxy in the package.json to communicate with my API. Everything is working smoothly with user authentication and CRUD actions. Now when I go to production, my user auth is telling me that I am unauthorized to make any call besides log in even when I have a session token.

My application controller where things seem to get hung up:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
include ActionController::Cookies
before_action :authorize

def authorize
  @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  render json: {error:["Not authorized"]}, status: :unauthorized unless @current_user
end
```

My Ruby terminal will output something like this when I log out or and other action

```
Started DELETE "/logout" for ::1 at 2021-09-08 14:20:06 -0400
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as HTML
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.12ms)
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 203)
```

Here is my user controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
wrap_parameters format: []

skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]
def create
    user = User.create(user_params)
    if user.valid?
        session[:user_id] = user.id 
        render json: user, status: :created
    else
        render json: {errors: user.errors.full_messages}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

def show 
    user = @current_user
    render json: user, status: :created
end

private

def user_params
    params.permit(:email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio, :join_date)
end
```

My sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:create]
def create
    user = User.find_by(username: params[:username])
    if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
        session[:user_id] = user.id
        render json: user, status: :created
    else
        render json: { errors: ["Invalid username or password"] }, status: :unauthorized
    end
end
def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    head = :no_content  
end
```

and my fetch calls are all fairly basic, like:

```
function signin(username, password) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
    }).then((r) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (r.ok) {
            r.json().then((user) => {
                setUser(user);
            });
        } else {
            r.json().then((err) => setErrors(err.errors));
        }
    });
}
```

Why would this happen when everything was working fine when I proxy to the API URL but when I explicitly call it, rails can't find the `session[:user_id]` to authenticate? I have spent days trying different things, looking for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

So my assumption is that authentication should be stored in a cookie which is passed (implicitly) as a header in your front-end calls and should be passed through to the API. If you're 100% sure the proxy is working locally then i'd see what's different about your production setup.

Check if the cookie headers are being sent to the react app.
Check if the cookie headers are arriving in your rails app.

Cookies can have security settings such as only being sent over HTTPS or only to specific domains. Your production setup may differ in terms of the default security settings being used by your react server or rails.